# Show null counts with a condition of <= 2

Tags: sql, oracle, count, null, left-join

Currently trying to find diagnosed diseases that have been diagnosed between 0-2 times. 
i am able to show how many times each disease has been diagnosed, including 0, but as soon as i try to view the ones that have a count of 0-2, my query doesn't work.

this gets me the counts (including 0):

```
select disease.name, count(diagnosed.diseaseid) as timesdiagnosed
from disease
left join diagnosed on disease.diseaseid = diagnosed.diseaseid
group by disease.name;
```

and this code doesn't work :

```
select disease.name, count(diagnosed.diseaseid) as timesdiagnosed
from disease
left join diagnosed on disease.diseaseid = diagnosed.diseaseid
group by disease.name
order by disease.name
having count(diagnosed.diseaseid) <= 2;
```

My RDMBS is oracle.

Comment: what do you mean "does not work"? Error or no result or wrong result. What du you mean with the keyword "null"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`having` clause should go before the `order by` and after the `group by`:

```
select disease.name, count(diagnosed.diseaseid) as timesdiagnosed
from disease
left join diagnosed on disease.diseaseid = diagnosed.diseaseid
group by disease.name
having count(diagnosed.diseaseid) <= 2
order by disease.name
```

Comment: So all i had wrong was the order of two of my statements?

Comment: @Shandep: Yep, I think so.